# How to add an attribute to Django request object

Tags: django, authentication, jwt, middleware

I try to add the `business` attribute to the request object by using my own middleware, it nicely works with `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` and I can use `request.business` in my views. But when I try to authenticate with JWT method (`rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication`) when my middleware code is run `request.user` is set to `AnonymouseUser` so can't fetch business associated with `user`? Why did this happen?

```
# middleware.py

class MyMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.business = None

        if request.user.is_authenticated and hasattr(request.user, 'business'):
            request.business = request.user.business

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

Middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'my_app.middleware.MyMiddleware',
]
```

rest_framework settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Comment: Can you show your list of middlewares to see how they are ordered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and Middleware which uses request.user is always Anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240832/django-and-middleware-which-uses-request-user-is-always-anonymous)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` are not processed in middleware process, but in the view itself. What is giving you the proper user when using session is the Django's `AuthenticationMiddleware` and REST Framework is just using this value when the session authentication is enabled.

To solve that, you can do one of the following:

- Move adding `request.business` to the views (for example by adding some class that all your views will inherit from)
- Move JWT authentication into Django middlewares (this has a side effect of DRF enforcing CSRF checks by default when user is logged in)