# Django - request.user.username inside an @api_view(['GET,'POST']) request function

Tags: django

So I have an @api_view which is based on a post request, which has some parameters sent from the front end. I want to get the username of the loggedin user to perfrom some other actions. But ***request.user.username*** always returns "Anonymous User".

If I call ***request.user.username*** outside of this request function I get the logged in user returned correctly. What is going wrong here?

```
@api_view(['GET','POST']) 
def function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data 
        # perform some function
        username = request.user.username
        # perform some other actions
```

Comment: what about the : after the if? even that is a mistake here?

Comment: Now its correct

Comment: try if request.method == 'GET' and try to print the username once

Comment: are you using custom user model (which is different from a custom user PROFILE model)?

Comment: Not a custom user model no. Just a custom user password encryption.

Comment: see if this is of any relevance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376985/django-request-user-is-always-anonymous-user