# Custom Django Login Form Not Logging Users In

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a login page for my webapp. I am able to log users in through the official admin page, but when I use my page the request.user is not logged in.

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

                login(request, user)

                return render(request, 'AllocationWebapp/browse.html', {})
        else:
            print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
            return render(request, 'AllocationWebapp/browse.html', {'error': "Invalid login details supplied."})
    else:
        return render(request, 'AllocationWebapp/login.html', {})
```

user is being set correctly, but after login request.user is still AnonymousUser and not logged in.

Comment: add the imports for functions `authenticate()` and `login()`?

Comment: I have `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login` at the top of views.py

Comment: check what the `user` variable contain after you call authenticate `None`?

Comment: `print(user)` prints the username and `print(user.is_authenticated)` prints True

Comment: Are you using a custom `User` model?

Comment: anyway, have a look at these answers: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376985/django-request-user-is-always-anonymous-user)

Comment: I have a userprofile that extends the auth user, but just for this login I'm just using the default user. `authenticate()` is returning a real user not an anonymous one. I've had a look through the answers to the question and they seem to be for if you have a custom user and not using the default one.

Comment: check your redirect url is exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working using the built in `authenticate` and `login` functions, so I used this as a workaround.

`user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)`

`request.session['user'] = user.id`

Then when I need to know if a user is logged in I just check request.