# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x048C7E90>

Tags: python, post, django-rest-framework

> ```
> Cannot cast AnonymousUser to int.
> Are you trying to use it in place of User?
> ```

I am unsure how to adjust my code to stop generating this error when i make a post request to my url.  I have attached code for my serializers, views and models.

```
class ActivitySessionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    activity_name = serializers.CharField(min_length=1, max_length=100)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        activity, created = Activity.objects.get_or_create(name=validated_data['activity_name'], 
        owner=self.context['request'].user)

        return ActivitySession.objects.create(activity=activity, start_time=datetime.datetime.now())



class StartSessionView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.ActivitySessionSerializer


    User = get_user_model()
    
    class ActivityType(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Activity(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        activity_type = models.ForeignKey(ActivityType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    class ActivitySession(models.Model):
        activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        start_time = models.DateTimeField()
        end_time = models.DateTimeField()


    urlpatterns = [
        path('starting_session/', views.StartSessionView.as_view()),
    ]
```

I believe i solved it by changing line

```
Activity.objects.get_or_create(name=validated_data['activity_name'], 
        owner=self.context['request'].user)
```

to

```
Activity.objects.get_or_create(name=validated_data['activity_name'], 
        owner=self.context['request'].user.id)
```

I had to add id field specifically instead of the total user object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ForeignKey to AnonymousUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512180/foreignkey-to-anonymoususer)

Answer (score 11):

just need to add request.user.id /// this will solve for sure..

Answer (score 4):

`AnonymousUser` has `id=None` and `pk=None`, so is not directly useable in this situation. Instead, the recommendation is to [create an instance of user that reflects an anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60512592/7954504).

Answer (score 4):

For those who also come here, one possible bug is (and this is what I encountered):

> you might call the anonymous `user` instance somewhere else through `foreignkey` or `reverse foreignkey`.

For example, in my code:

1. I received the anonymous request in my `CustomView` like this:

```py
class CustomView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomSerializer
    queryset =CustomModel.objects.all()
```

2. The `CustomModel` of the `CustomView` has a reverse foreignkey-`which_model`, like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class CustomModel(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Custom name", max_length=256)
 
class CustomRecord(BaseModel):
    which_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="related user")
    which_model = models.ForeignKey("CustomModel", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="related model",related_name="user_record",)
```

3. To get the related `CustomRecord` instance simultaneously when getting the `CustomModel` instance in the anonymous request, I used the  `SerializerMethodField` in the `CustomSerializer` like this:

```py
class CustomSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    related_user_record = SerializerMethodField(read_only=True, source="user_record")
    def get_related_user_record(self, obj):
        # This is where the problem is !!!!
        user_record = CustomRecord.objects.filter(
            which_model=obj.id, which_user=self.context["request"].user
        )
        if not user_record:
            return None
        else:
            return CustomRecordSerializer(user_record.get()).data
```

Because I used the `self.context["request"].user` in `get_related_user_record` function, django try to convert the id of user instance to int;
**However, like [@Brad Solomon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971383/5163091) said, the anonymous user's id or pk is None.**, that's where the error comes from. And honestly, djano didn't do well in reporting the bug source when this error happens.

What I did to sovle this problem is that I added a check before using the user instance, to see if it's an anonymous user, like this:

```py
def get_related_user_record(self, obj):
    # check if it's an anonymous user
    if not self.context["request"].user.pk:
        return None
    # This is where the problem is !!!!
    user_record = CustomRecord.objects.filter(
        which_model=obj.id, which_user=self.context["request"].user
    )
    if not user_record:
        return None
    else:
        return CustomRecordSerializer(user_record.get()).data
```