# I want to create and update UserProfile object with OneToOne User object field and create an api in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**I'm new in Django rest framework, I tried my whole day but can't do it,I want to do full crud operation in my UserProfile Model which have a OneToOne field user, User can only update their own profile and in UserProfile create or update user shouldn't update User[username], How can i achieve it Please Help me**

**views.py**

```
class Profile(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            _profile = request.user.userprofile
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            _profile = {
                "phone": '',
                "image": '',

            }
        finally:
            content = {
                "first_name": request.user.first_name,
                "last_name": request.user.last_name,
                'phone': _profile.phone,
                'image': _profile.image
            }
            return Response(content, status=200)
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**Error**

```
AttributeError at /api/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Aleem\PycharmProjects\E-Commerce\src\e_commerce_project\api\views.py in get, line 34
Python Executable:  E:\OFFICCE WORK\e-commerce\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Aleem\\PycharmProjects\\E-Commerce\\src\\e_commerce_project',
 'C:\\Users\\Aleem\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Aleem\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Aleem\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Aleem\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'E:\\OFFICCE WORK\\e-commerce',
 'E:\\OFFICCE WORK\\e-commerce\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 23 Jul 2020 09:49:23 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

From this line:

```py
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

I believe your problem is that you didn't regulate the users carefully. `AnonymousUser` is an object that is representing a user that is not authenticated. For this object, `id` is none, `permissions` is an empty array -- basically you won't expect to find any data here.

The thing that you should do is to add [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator): a login-required decorator. This forces the user to be authenticated properly before proceeding (or just user.is_authenticated() in case you don't want to apply this to the entire view.

If you are logged in and AnonymousUser still persists, you may want to check out other threads regarding this problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377111).